# Are there any benefits to deploying via Workbench instead of Change Sets?

Tags: apex, deployment

Can someone please elaborate on what the pros and cons are of Salesforce deployment using Workbench over Change Sets?

Comment: As soon as you need to deploy something between to unrelated environments, you can not use changeset

Comment: This post seems kind of broad and also demonstrates no research on your part. Is it something you've looked into? Are you confused on any particular point?

Comment: I've looked into this quite a lot but there's not a single source of documentation that i've come across which explains the pros and cons of Workbench vs Change Set in its entirety. That's my aim here: to either find that documentation or collate enough answers together than can serve as a single source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change sets tend to be easier to use, because you can automatically identify required dependencies between objects, while the workbench requires that the admin/developer gets all the files correct, which can be a challenge even for experienced, technically-minded people. The workbench tends to deploy faster than change sets in wall-clock-time, because you don't have to wait for the intermediate upload process, which typically takes up to 30 minutes to become available. It also lets you deploy to arbitrary orgs, unlike change sets, which can only deploy to related orgs (e.g. production and a sandbox, or two related sandboxes).

Comment: Thanks as always :) is the 'checkOnly' deployment option the same as the 'validate' via Change set?

Comment: @AndyHitchings They are functionally the same. Both validate all elements, run all tests, and allow Quick Deploy afterwards.